# Doubling the ends doesn't alter the space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surfaces

Let $C$ be a compact totally disconnected infinite subset of $\big\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: x\geq 0\big\}$. [So, $C$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of Cantor Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395931/is-any-compact-metric-totally-disconnected-space-homeomorphic-to-a-compact-subsp). Let $C^\dagger:=\big\{(-x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:(x,y)\in C\big\} $.

> Is $\Bbb R^2\backslash C$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2\backslash (C\cup
>  C^\dagger)$?

When $C\subseteq[0,1]$ itself is the Cantor Set then I guess $\Bbb R^2\backslash C\cong \Bbb R^2\backslash (C\cup C^\dagger)$.

$\textbf{Context:}$ Note that the [space of ends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)) of $\Bbb R^2\backslash C$ is $C\sqcup \{\infty\}$, so the question is equivalent to saying that doubling the ends doesn't alter the space.

> If the above question has a negative answer in general, then under
> what extra conditions on $C$ the same question has an affirmative
> answer?

Comment: It's not quite true that the space of ends of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus C$ is $C$, since there's one other end (at infinity).

Comment: Thanks, for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $C = \{1\} \times \bigl(\{0\} \cup \{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb N\} \bigr)$ then $C \cup C^\dagger$ is not homeomorphic to $C$, but if two spaces are homeomorphic then their end spaces are homeomorphic as well.

In general, your question is equivalent to asking when $C \cup C^\dagger$ is homeomorphic to $C$. This is true when $C$ is the whole Cantor set, and I *think* it is generally false when $C$ is homeomorphic to a countable ordinal $\alpha$ for which the $\alpha ^{\text{th}}$ derived set is empty, such as the counterexample I gave above: the least such $\alpha$ will be a successor ordinal, and the $\alpha-1^\text{st}$ derived set will be finite; the cardinality of that set is doubled when you replace $C$ by $C \cup C^\dagger$. There's probably some more true examples, e.g. when the first derived set of $C$ is a Cantor set.

Comment: $\omega$ is an unfortunate choice of variable for an arbitrary countable ordinal!

Comment: @LeeMosher  So, if $C$ itself is Cantor set of $[0,1]$ the question has a positive answer, right? But more than that I can not expect in general. Sorry, I do have not enough knowledge in ordinal.

Comment: Yeah, my education in set theory and ordinals etc. is very scattered, and I kind of have to make notation up as I go along. So what's a good arbitrary ordinal notation? @EricWofsey

Comment: The history of topology, and in particular of closed subsets of $\mathbb R$, is very closely intertwined with the history of ordinal numbers. It's a good thing to learn. @User

Comment: Usually Greek letters are used for ordinal variables, but not $\omega$, since that refers to one specific ordinal (the least infinite ordinal).  Common choices are $\alpha$ or $\xi$.